# Realtime time message in iPhone SDK

Tags: ios4, websocket

I'm finding a way to realtime messaging in iPhone SDK. iPhone Safari doesn't support Web socket. Apple push notification is working only on application is close. I want to make like chat program with real time. There is other way except web socket ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely that the next version of iOS (4.2) will add WebSockets support. [iOS 4.2 should be out this month](http://www.ipadnewsdaily.com/apple-ios-42-bigger-than-the-beatles-1023/).

You might looked at [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/) if you control the server side too. Socket.IO is a JavaScript library for the client and server that uses the best communication transport that both ends support starting with native WebSockets, then a Flash based WebSockets fallback, then various long-poll/COMET options. The API on client and server sides is very much like the normal WebSockets API regardless of which underlying transport is used. It would allow you to use the WebSockets protocol when available and fall back to something that still works when you don't have WebSockets (without requiring you to use a different API).

Answer (score 0):

You can do some of the traditional "comet" tricks like long-polling or a forever `iframe`, however I'm not sure any of those are as concise as WebSockets.

If you're looking for a paired client / server side library, I would look at [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/).